# Eclipse/Java: adding a .css file to default package

Tags: java, eclipse, javafx

I have just added a `.css` file to the `default package` (right-click over `default package` > New..) in a plain Java project, but as you can see below, the file (`NewFile.css`) is **outside** the package.. why?

[image]

This is some strange for me, since I don't have any problem to add a new `.css` file to a JavaFX application as you can see here (`applications.css`):

[image]

Comment: As a best practice avoid usage of default packages.

Comment: @UlukBiy what should I do with the default package? should I remove it?

Comment: No just give some name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Packages are created to hold only java files. You can create new source folder say `resources` in the project level and add .css files there.